# Facebook - You don't have required permission to access this profile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a service that let's users create facebook ads with a custom audience based on our database of emails.

Before creating the facebook ad I want to create a preview of the ad. This works just fine when I login in with my own account (admin of facebook app) but fails when logging in as test user.

This is what the user will do:
1. Visit the website of the service.
2. Login using Facebook account with scope: public_profile,email,manage_pages,publish_pages,business_management,ads_management
3. Select facebook page to use 
4. Create AdCreative. From this an ad preview can be made. But it fails creating an Adcreative and gives me the following error:

```
"error":{"message":"Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":1341012,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"No permission to access this profile","error_user_msg":"You don't have required permission to access this profile","fbtrace_id":"EgTeMOXPCUp"}}
```

The access token as well as ad account belongs to the facebook app. I tried to use the page access token as well but then I don't have permission to access the ad account.
This is code:

```
function fbadcreative($url, $message, $carasoul, $fbtoken, $pageid){

$calength = count($carasoul);
$children = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $calength; $i++){
    $caitem = $carasoul[$i];
    $caitem['hash'] = fbaddimage($caitem['picture'], $caitem['id']);
    $child = (new AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachment())->setData(array(
        AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::LINK => $caitem['link'],
        AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::NAME => $caitem['name'],
        AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::DESCRIPTION => $caitem['description'],
        AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::IMAGE_HASH => $caitem['hash'],
    ));
    $children[] = $child;
}
$link_data = new AdCreativeLinkData();
$link_data->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => $url,
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CAPTION => $url,
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MESSAGE => $message,
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MULTI_SHARE_END_CARD => false,
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MULTI_SHARE_OPTIMIZED => false,
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CHILD_ATTACHMENTS => $children,
));
$object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => $pageid,
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
));

$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_<accountid>');
$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => $url,
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));
try {
    $creative->create();
     return $creative->id;
    //return $creative->read(array(AdCreativeFields::ID,));
} catch (FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' . var_dump($e);
    $previousException = $e->getPrevious();
    // Do some further processing on $previousException
    exit;
}
```

Comment: did you eventually figure this out?

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an older post, but it might be interesting for others to read how to solve this.

You need to give the user that requests via api the Advertise and analyze permissions on the PAGE the ad creative will be created for.

Example request here using the graph explorer:
`page_id/assigned_users?user=system_user_id&tasks=['ADVERTISE', 'ANALYZE']`

Comment: I've tried to da that but I have the following error when trying to assigned my admin systemuser with the page event if I set the business field
```You do not have permission to perform this action. This action requires that you can MANAGE_PERMISSIONS on a managing business account.  Or it requires that you can ADMINISTER on this object Note: to use do this action on behalf of a business account the \"business\" field must be set.```
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In my case i am getting this same error due to giving the wrong page Id , i was giving the another page id that was not linked to this ad account.