# Facebook sdk error: "Application does not have permission for this action"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I'm trying to use facebook java sdk to create ads. I'm able to create AdCampaign and AdSet, but when I'm trying to create AdCreative, it returns with error:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "error_subcode": 1341012,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "No permission to access this profile",
    "error_user_msg": "You don't have required permission to access this profile",
    "fbtrace_id": "Gvc9OPtfxrb"
}
```

}

To create APIContext, I'm using Access Token, generated from "System User" section under Business settings and App Secret from application settings. 
To create AdAccount, I'm using Ad Account Id.

I guess I miss some Id or Token, because I can go Ads Manager and do everything I need from ui, so looks like I have enough permissions.

Could you help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Were you managed to fix this? I have the same problem right now.

Comment: See here how to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371143/9036543
Probably this is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue wherein we were able to create campaigns and adsets using the API token generated for the ad account but not able to publish ads.
The problem was that the ad account for which the API token was generated had access to pages and the ad manager account but in addition to that we will have to give the user access to the page & ad account and apps. Because FB assumes that some user is running the code and not the ad account and hence users should be given access.

Just go to users -> People and add assets and the respective page, ad accounts and apps and run the code.